# Want to know if I can make buttons which perform a function in Python GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, text-based

So I'm making this text based adventure game in python (with pre installed modules like random and time) and I've already made it for the console.
But , I want to make an app out of it in which there are a few buttons located below and when clicked they will perform a specific function like fighting or fleeing or inventory.
So I wanted to ask if its possible or not and if possible, which GUI module will best suit me (I need one which makes a neat app and is easy too!).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you Arcade library: https://opensource.com/article/18/4/easy-2d-game-creation-python-and-arcade